# Is it possible to use React Split Pane with more than two panes?

Tags: reactjs, splitpane

We are using react-split-pane in our project, but it is not working for more than two panes.
In the page we should have three panes with two resizers, but the third panel is not shown using react-split-pane so I suppose is not suppported.

I also tried react-multi-split-pane but the resizers do not work.

Do you know if there is a way to use react-split-pane with three panes or if there are other valid alternatives?